# Using caption in longtable cell

Tags: tables, color, captions, longtable, multicolumn

I want to add a table caption with a label in a `longtable` environment. The caption should appear in a multicolumn, colored table cell.

The following doesn't work as expected:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!40}\caption{My Table Caption}\label{table1}} \\
    \hline
    1 & 2\\ \hline
    3 & 4\\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Changing the `\caption` into, for example, `\textbf` works.

How can I get the `\caption` working in a `longtable` cell?

Comment: Why put the caption in a cell?

Comment: From the `longtable` documentation: "The `\caption{...}` command is essentially equivalent to `\multicolumn{n}{c}{\parbox{\LTcapwidth}{...}}` where`n` is  the  number  of  columns  of  the  table".

Comment: @Bernard: I want to add the caption on top of the table, alignment center with a grey background, full table width and a black border. I am happy if you can show me another possibility than a table cell.

Comment: I would copy the definition of `\LT@makecaption` from the package and add the colours etc there  (`\LT@mcol` in that definition is essentially `\multicolumn`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, thanks to the comments above!

After redefining `\LT@makecaption` I could solve it by only adding `\caption{...}\label{...} \\` to the table.

Here is the working version from the code above:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

% redefine longtable caption
\makeatletter
\def\LT@makecaption#1#2#3{%
    \multicolumn{\LT@cols}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!40}\textbf{#2: }\textbf{#3}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \caption{My Table Caption}\label{table1}\\
    \hline
    1 & 2\\ \hline
    3 & 4\\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```